# Consecutive value after and new level of factor in R

Tags: r, r-factor

I have the following sample

```
id <- c("a","b","a","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","c")
SOG <- c(4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9)
data <- data.frame(id,SOG)
```

I would like in a new column the cumulative value when SOG == 0.
with the following code

```
tmp <- rle(SOG)                                    #run length encoding: 
tmp$values <- tmp$values == 0                      #turn values into logicals 
tmp$values[tmp$values] <- cumsum(tmp$values[tmp$values]) #cumulative sum of TRUE values 
inverse.rle(tmp)                                   #inverse the run length encoding
```

I create the column "stop":

```
data$Stops <- inverse.rle(tmp)
```

and I can get in it:

```
[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

But I would like to have instead

```
[1] 0 0 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 0
```

I mean that when the level of the factor "id" is different from the previous row, I want to jump to the next "stop" (i+1).

Comment: Here is a variant `with(data,  (!SOG) * (cumsum(!SOG & c(FALSE,id[-1]!= id[-length(id)]))))`

Comment: @akrun, thank you. When I edit my sample with `id <- c("a","b","a","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","c","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
SOG <- c(4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,1,5,3,0,0,4,0,0,1)`, it does not go to 5 and then 6 for the last examples for id a

Comment: Thanks a lot @Akrun. I am currently working on a bigger sample, I will continue tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[, v1 := if(all(!SOG)) c(TRUE, id[-1]!= id[-.N]) else
     rep(FALSE, .N), .(grp = rleid(SOG))][,cumsum(v1)*(!SOG)]
#[1] 0 0 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 6 6 0
```

Using the old data

```
setDT(data)[, v1 := if(all(!SOG)) c(TRUE, id[-1]!= id[-.N]) 
       else rep(FALSE, .N), .(grp = rleid(SOG))][,cumsum(v1)*(!SOG)]
#[1] 0 0 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 0
```

#### data

```
id <- c("a","b","a","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","c","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a", "a")
SOG <- c(4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,1,5,3,0,0,4,0,0,1)
data1 <- data.frame(id, SOG, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: it worked. I have now a new issue but it should be fine, thanks!

Comment: @Floni Glad to know that it works.  If you have a new issue, please do post as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

have a look a the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(
    Stops = ifelse(
      SOG > 0,
      0,
      cumsum(SOG == 0 & lag(id) != id)
    )
  )
```

Comment: The answer may _use_ `dplyr` but it is not _dependent_ on it: `data$Stops <- with(data, ifelse(SOG > 0, 0, cumsum(SOG == 0 & lag(id) != id)))` is perfectly readable and does not require the introduction of another package for the SO. (`lag()` has been around alot longer longer than `dplyr` has :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I edit my sample with `id <- c("a","b","a","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","c","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
SOG <- c(4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,1,5,3,0,0,4,0,0,1)` , it does not work...  For the id a, the stops is stucked to 4 but it should go to 5 and then 4 (b was 4 already)